# Ionic view strange behaviour

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-view

I am having a strange behaviour when I upload the app to ionic view.
Currently I am trying to persist an image from the camera to Parse using the plugin: `cordova-plugin-file` .

Having the device connected by USB and running `ionic run android` is working fine. 
But using `ionic upload`, then from the ionic view application is not working.

Running from the  Ionic View application the code `alert(window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL)`
displays `undefined` but if runs directly on android or deploying using android studio then it is running fine.

Does someone experience the same behaviour?
Does ionic view not support cordova-plugin-file?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the problem

http://docs.ionic.io/docs/view-usage

The plugin cordova-plugin-file is not supported by ionic view app